# In Outlook profile how to change check name server

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2013

From where outlook get "Server Detail" when we click on "Check Name" while creating profile in outlook.
In my case Outlook get server detail EXCHCAS.XYZ.COM that is my netbios name or Internal CAS server name.
How i can change **EXCHCAS.XYZ.COM** to CAS External Name **mail.XYZ.COM**

Answer (score 2):

That is coming from autodiscover and it is getting populated with the CASArray name that corresponds to the mailbox. The external name should get populated in another spot that has to do with the Outlook Anywhere settings.  On the account settings -> more settings -> connections tab is where the external entry needs to be populated.

EXCHCAS.XYZ.COM should be populated in the account settings box.  mail.XYZ.COM should be in the Outlook Anywhere proxy settings connection box buried in the settings.  The internal CASArray name should be different than the external name or when it comes time to upgrade Exchange versions you will have a very difficult time moving forward.

Of course you also have to have Outlook Anywhere enabled on the Exchange Server to allow that connection to be made by the client.